# Use new field "Full Name" to replace "First Name" and "Last Name" in Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, frontend, knockoutjs

My idea is to use to add a new field called "Full Name" and it will fill out the "First Name" and the "Last Name" while you type in the checkout.
I have almost everything ready but I can't let know to "First Name" and "Last Name" that those values were updated.
Let show what I did and someone can tell me what I'm missing.

1. Edit the frontend/di.xml

/app/code/CustomVendor/CustomModule/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="checkout_custom_fields" type="CustomVendor\CustomModule\Plugin\Checkout\Model\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
</config>
```

2.Add the LayoutProcessor.php 
app/code/CustomVendor/CustomModule/Plugin/Checkout/Model/LayoutProcessor.php

```
    /**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 */
public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
) {
    $shippingConfiguration = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
    ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'];

    $shippingConfiguration = $this->setFullName($shippingConfiguration);

    return $jsLayout;
}

    /**
 * Set "Full Name"
 * @param array $shippingConfiguration
 * @return array
 */
private function setFullName(array  $shippingConfiguration){

    $shippingConfiguration['full_name'] = [
        'component' => 'AdditionalProducts_AdditionalProductsModule/js/checkout/abstract',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
            'options' => [],
            'id' => 'full-name'
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.full_name',
        'label' => __('Full Name'),
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'validation' => [
            'required-entry' => true
        ],
        'sortOrder' => 0,
        'id' => 'full-name',
    ];

    return $shippingConfiguration;
}
```

3. Added abstract.js but with a custome code
   app/code/CustomVendor/CustomModule//view/frontend/web/js/checkout/abstract.js

   ```
   /**
    * Update whether value differs from default value
    */
   setDifferedFromDefault: function () {
       var value = typeof this.value() != 'undefined' && this.value() !== null ? this.value() : '',
           defaultValue = typeof this.default != 'undefined' && this.default !== null ? this.default : '';

       this.isDifferedFromDefault(value !== defaultValue);

       this.setFirstLastNameFromFullName(value);
   },

   /**
    * Extract from the 'Full Name' the 'First' and 'Last' Name
    *
    * @param value
    */
   setFirstLastNameFromFullName : function(value){
       var fullValue = value;
       var lastSpacePos = fullValue.lastIndexOf(" ");
       var nameLimit = 10;
       var lastNameLimit = 10;

       if (lastSpacePos > 0) { // Ignore values with no space character
           if(fullValue.substring(0, lastSpacePos).length < nameLimit){
               // Update "firstName"
               $($('[name="shippingAddress.firstname"]').find('input')[0]).val(fullValue.substring(0, lastSpacePos));
           }
           if(fullValue.substring(lastSpacePos + 1).length < lastNameLimit){
               // Update "lastName"
               $($('[name="shippingAddress.lastname"]').find('input')[0]).val(fullValue.substring(lastSpacePos + 1));
           }
       }else{
           if(fullValue.length < nameLimit){
               // Update "firstName"
               $($('[name="shippingAddress.firstname"]').find('input')[0]).val(fullValue);
               console.log(this.firstname);
           }
       }
   },
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I found it!!!
The solution was in this [page](https://magento-devdocs.github.io/devdocs-for-tests/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_custom_checkbox.html).

I made two changes:

1. Set "track" to **FirstName** and **LastName** in the **LayoutProcessor.php**.
2. Update javascript function.

   1. LayoutProcessor.php

   ```
    /**
   ```

   - Set "Full Name"
   - @param array $shippingConfiguration
   - @return array
     */
     private function setFullName(array  $shippingConfiguration){

     $shippingConfiguration['full_name'] = [
         'component' => 'AdditionalProducts_AdditionalProductsModule/js/checkout/abstract',
         'config' => [
             'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
             'template' => 'ui/form/field',
             'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
             'options' => [],
             'id' => 'full-name'
         ],
         'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.full_name',
         'label' => __('Full Name'),
         'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
         'visible' => true,
         'validation' => [
             'required-entry' => true,
         ],
         'sortOrder' => 0,
         'id' => 'full-name',
     ];

     $shippingConfiguration = $this->makeTrackableFirstLastName($shippingConfiguration);

     return $shippingConfiguration;
     }

   /**

   - Track firstName and lastName
   - @param array $shippingConfiguration
   - @return array
     */
     private function makeTrackableFirstLastName(array  $shippingConfiguration){
     $shippingConfiguration['firstname']['tracks']['value'] = true;
     $shippingConfiguration['lastname']['tracks']['value'] = true;

     return $shippingConfiguration;
     }
3. abstract.js

   ```
   define([
   'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
   'mage/translate'
   ], function (AbstractField, $t) {
   'use strict';

   return AbstractField.extend({
       defaults: {
           modules: {
               firstname: '${ $.parentName }.firstname',
               lastname: '${ $.parentName }.lastname',
           }
       },

   hasChanged: function () {
       this._super();
       this.setFirstLastNameFromFullName();
   },

   /**
    * Extract from the 'Full Name' the 'First' and 'Last' Name
    */
   setFirstLastNameFromFullName : function(){
       var fullValue = this.value();
       var lastSpacePos = fullValue.lastIndexOf(" ");
       var nameLimit = 10;
       var lastNameLimit = 10;

       if (lastSpacePos > 0) { // Ignore values with no space character
           if(fullValue.substring(0, lastSpacePos).length < nameLimit){
               // Update "firstName"
               this.firstname().value(fullValue.substring(0, lastSpacePos));
           }
           if(fullValue.substring(lastSpacePos + 1).length < lastNameLimit){
               // Update "lastName"
               this.lastname().value(fullValue.substring(lastSpacePos + 1));
           }
       }else{
           if(fullValue.length < nameLimit){
               // Update "firstName"
               this.firstname().value(fullValue);
           }
       }
   },


   });
   });
   ```